# How we can embed "Text Editor" (any editor) in Laravel which will help us to store multiple images at once

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, editor

The question that I asked is that:how we can embed Text Editor in to the application of Laravel (php framework) through which we can do crud operation, moreover it can save multiple images in the database. I am using Mysql as a database and bootstrap (framework) as a front end, if somebody can help me in this that would be appreciated.

I wanted similar behaviour which is shown below
[image]
A editor with multiple images. I want to store the images through some text editor.
I am using summernote, and having trouble in saving multiple images via it if there is any other editor which would help me to store multiple images likewise above.

Comment: What are you asking here? Are you asking for a text editor recommendation (which is off-topic here) or have you already selected one, but are having trouble integrating it (in which case you need to add a lot more detail to your question)?

Comment: I wanted to know about the information that there is any way or editor which would help me to store multiple images.

Comment: "Any way" would be creating a form and an action to do that (meaning make one yourself). Asking for external libraries is [not on-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I worked with "summernote" but I wasn't able to store images via it, that is why I need a simple editor or a way or concept that would help me to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is called a Rich Text Editor. There are a good number of them out there but i will mention two most popular and highly customizable.

1. CKEditor - here install a plugin called CKFinder that will help you manage multiple images as you want.
2. TinyMCE - this is what wordpress uses.

I hope I answered your question?